# Independent saga call/responses across different instances of same component?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm a little new to react, redux, and sagas, but I'm getting the hang of things.

I have a component (`Results.jsx`) that displays results of a particular real-world event, through a saga calling an external API:

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.thing_id) {
        this.props.getResults(this.props.thing_id);
    }
}
```

...

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        prop1: state.apiReducer.thing_results.data1,
        prop2: state.apiReducer.thing_results.data2,
        fetching: state.apiReducer.fetching,
        error: state.apiReducer.error,
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        getResults: (thing_id) => dispatch({type: "RESULTS_DATA_REFRESH", payload: thing_id})
    };
};
```

This all works great. Until... Well, I'm using a tabbed interface that lets me dynamically add a bunch of additional instances of `Results.jsx` so I can see a bunch of different results sets all on the same screen.

The problem is that when a new instance of the `Results.jsx` component loads, and gets data from the `RESULTS_DATA_REFRESH` dispatch, **all** of the instances of the `Results.jsx` component update with the data that comes back. They **all** show the same data.

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to have a particular instance of a component **only** listen to results from what it itself dispatched. I thought that's the way sagas were supposed to work?

Any help is appreciated!

**Edits/Answers:**

Reducer function is pretty textbook, looks like:

```
const initialState = {
    fetching: false,
    error: null,
    thing_results: {
        data1: null,
        data2: null,
    },
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

        //...

        case "RESULTS_DATA_REFRESH":
            return {...state, fetching: true};
        case "RESULTS_DATA_SUCCESS":
            return {...state, fetching: false, thing_results: action.results.data, error: null};
        case "RESULTS_DATA_FAILURE":
            return {...state, fetching: false, thing_results: null, error: action.error};

        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Comment: How your `reducer` function looks like?

Comment: Instead of a single key in your state, you need a collection.  The reducer should only reduce state for the instance.

Comment: @Alex added code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sagas are nothing but a middleware to offload your async tasks and store writes out of the View layer. Ultimately the prop that comes to your component depends on how you store it. Specifically in this case if `prop1` and `prop2` are picked up from the same place in the store, it'll come as the same value in all instances of `Results`.

If you require different data for different instances, section it based on some unique id mapped to the instance. You reducer would look like :

```
const apiReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "RESULTS_DATA_REFRESH":
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.payload]: { data: null, fetching: true }
      };
    case "RESULTS_DATA_SUCCESS":
      return {
        ...state,
        /** You should be getting back the id from the api response.
         * Else append the id in the success action from your api saga.
         */
        [action.payload.id]: { data: action.results.data, fetching: false }
      };
    case "RESULTS_DATA_FAILURE":
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.payload.id]: {
          data: null,
          fetching: false,
          error: action.error
        }
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

/** Other reducers */
const otherReducerA = function() {};
const otherReducerB = function() {};

export default combineReducers({ apiReducer, otherReducerA, otherReducerB });
```

And access it like :

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    data: state.apiReducer
  };
};

function Results({ data, thing_id }) {
  return <div>{data[thing_id].data}</div>;
}
```

Comment: I've read this a few times, and I almost understand. Where would I set up that `job_results.thing_id_1.data1` structure? The reducer? I'd have to do some finagling to get the thing_id argument that was passed to the dispatch, I suppose...

Comment: Updated answer with a sample reducer